# Ezra's Force Abilities and "Animals"

Tags: star-wars

Over the course of the 2 seasons of rebels, there are a few examples of Ezra's force abilities to either communicate or to influence non-intelligent life forms in the galaxy.  One example can be found in the episodes named "Empire Day" and "Gathering Forces" which you can see on the wikipedia site [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_Rebels_episodes) and spefically mentiones that Ezra is being trained in this regard and uses the force to  However in one of the latest episodes of Rebels from Season 3,

> He is not able to communicate with the spiders on the world Atollon where the Bendu lives and mentions that he does not have that ability.

Is this an oversight on the Rebels writers?  Or am i not remembering something that would help clear up this question?

Comment: I assume that not all animals are able to be controlled.

Answer (score 3):

### He probably could influence the krykna, if he could let go of his fear

Ezra had previously tried to get along with the krykna (though not necessarily through the Force), and been unsuccessful. From "The Holocrons of Fate (S03E02):

> KANAN: Stay behind me! Ezra, you’re making it worse! It’s possible to
>   get along with them.
>
> EZRA: Mmm, I tried that, remember? They almost ripped my face off.

The spiders seem to be hypersensitive to fear or violent intentions (indeed, it is likely that they are Force Sensitive to some degree). Of course, once Ezra can overcome his desire to ignite his lightsaber at the first sign of conflict, he can get along with them better.

But, to a lesser degree, this is precisely what prevented Ezra from communicating with a more mundane loth-cat many episodes earlier, in “Empire Day” (S01, E07):

> EZRA: I don’t think he wants to connect!
>
> KANAN: You’re resisting. He can sense it.

Since the krykna are more sensitive to fear and violence than the loth-cats, they presumably pose a greater challenge. Then, too, we can’t forget that Ezra has been taking advice from the Sith holocron, which probably was leading him down a decidedly violent and fearful path. But if Ezra were able to calm himself sufficiently, let go of his fear, and reach out to the spiders, he could probably influence their behavior.